# sql query to find top 5 earners in a company(oracle db)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

My emp table:

```
ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000
SCOTT            3000
FORD             3000
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
```

for getting top 5 earners.i used the below query.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (SELECT ename, sal 
     from emp 
     ORDER BY sal desc)
WHERE rownum <= 5  
order by sal desc;
```

but I am getting output like this:

```
ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000
SCOTT            3000
FORD             3000
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
```

In this list, 'CLARK' is missing.

Employee 'CLARK' is also in top 5 earners list.how will I get if same salaries in the list. 
if I use dense_rank  ,'CLARK' will come on the list.

```
 SELECT  *  from 
(SELECT ename,SAL,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS RK FROM EMP)
WHERE RK <= 5
ORDER BY SAL DESC;



ENAME             SAL         RK
---------- ---------- ----------
KING             5000          1
SCOTT            3000          2
FORD             3000          2
JONES            2975          3
BLAKE            2850          4
CLARK            2450          5
```

Comment: I think your output is correct. CLARK is the 6th highest paid employee. What output you're are expecting, mention in the question.

Comment: You've asked for the top 5 and you have 5. And the usual definition of top 5 would not include CLARK (because CLARK is not part of a tie for fifth place). And why don't you want to use `dense_rank`?

Comment: suppose if its a tie at the 5 th position, then?

Comment: if I use dense_rank  ,'CLARK' will come on the list.

 SELECT  *  from 
(SELECT ename,SAL,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS RK FROM EMP)
WHERE RK <= 5
ORDER BY SAL DESC;



ENAME             SAL         RK
---------- ---------- ----------
KING             5000          1
SCOTT            3000          2
FORD             3000          2
JONES            2975          3
BLAKE            2850          4
CLARK            2450          5

Comment: Check my updated answer... Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL SERVER Query. Hope it helps you,

```
    SELECT Ename, Sal
    FROM     
        (
        SELECT ename, sal,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Sal DESC)RN from emp ORDER BY sal desc
        )D
    WHERE RN <= 5  
    ORDER BY sal desc;
```

Without `DENSE_RANK`, Try this Answer:

```
    SELECT Ename, Sal
    FROM emp
    WHERE sal IN(
        SELECT TOP 5 sal
        FROM @emp GROUP BY sal
        ORDER by sal DESC)
```

Comment: The OP says he doesn't want to use `DENSE_RANK`

Answer (score 0):

Including ties:

```
SELECT ename, sal 
from emp 
ORDER BY sal desc
fetch first 5 rows with ties
```

Excluding ties:

```
... fetch first 5 rows only
```

ANSI SQL, supported by newer Oracle versions. (I don't know if it is in 10g.)

Answer (score 0):

Determine the top five salaries in an inner select:

```
select e.ename, e.sal
  from emp e
 where e.sal in
       (select ee.sal
          from emp ee
         group by ee.sal
         order by ee.sal desc fetch first 5 rows only) -- top 5 salaries
 order by e.sal desc, e.ename asc;
```